# selective printing from a list

Tags: python

Say for an example, I've a list like this:

```
q_list = [('94.vmtest2', 'sgmops', 'Andy Hays', '27/04 00:27:26', 'C', '27/04 00:28:31', 'vmtest1.hep', 'express', '00:00:10', '00:01:04'), 
          ('96.vmtest2', 'sgmops', 'John Dee', '27/04 01:27:26', 'C', '27/04 01:28:33', 'vmtest1.hep', 'short', '00:00:09', '00:01:06'),
          ('99.vmtest2', 'sgmops', 'Andy Hays', '27/04 07:19:56', 'C', '27/04 07:21:12', 'vmtest1.hep', 'express', '00:00:10', '00:01:14'), 
          ('103.vmtest2', 'sgmops', 'John Dee', '27/04 14:08:00', 'C', '27/04 14:09:16', 'vmtest1.hep', 'express', '00:00:10', '00:01:16'),
          ('102.vmtest2', 'sgmops', 'John Dee', '27/04 14:02:38', 'C', '27/04 14:10:12', 'vmtest1.hep', 'short', '00:00:10', '00:01:10')]
```

which is formed from the log files. and then I have a dictionary like this:

```
q_dict = {'username': 'johndee', 'queue': 'short'}
```

which is formed from a query string (the user input). What I want is to print [first 8 items of] the only lines from the list match with the value in the dictionary. In this case, I'll only print these two lines:

```
96.vmtest2   sgmops  John Dee  27/04 01:27:26  C  27/04 01:28:33  vmtest1.hep  short
102.vmtest2  sgmops  John Dee  27/04 14:02:38  C  27/04 14:10:12  vmtest1.hep  short
```

In fact it doesn't have to be a dictionary at all; the user input (command-line argument) is like this:

```
'formatDate(%m/%d) == 4/27 && username == John Dee && queue == short'
```

and I'm creating the dictionary out of that. Any idea how can I do that? Thanks in advance for any help. Cheers!!

Comment: what exactly is the user allowed to give as input? (how complex can it be, i see ANDs, can there be ORs as well, grouping with parentheses, etc?)

Comment: I don't think I'm gonna allow `or` of any kind at the moment (I don't see much point using "or" in my case). So, I'm gonna stick to the `&&` for the time being and it should be only `&&`. Anything thing else in the input-string (other then "&&" and "==") is an invalid query. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach is to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), for instance to filter by username:

```
[x for x in q_list if x[2] == 'John Dee']
```

You can also use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filter(lambda x: x[2] == 'John Dee', q_list)
```

You can thus use your `q_dict` to filter by user and/or queue easily.

```
[x for x in q_list if [x[2].lower().replace(' ', ''), x[7]] == q_dict.values()]
```

As suggested in [Space_C0wb0y's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088698/selective-printing-from-a-list/6089057#6089057), using [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) would be a good approach, you can map out the fields rather easily:

```
fields =  ['field1', 'field2', 'username', 'field4', 'field5', 'field6', 'field7', 'queue', 'field9', 'field10']
Item = namedtuple('Item', fields)
```

For the sake of the argument, let's convert the tuples in your list to namedtuples:

```
q_namedtuple = [Item(*x) for x in q_list]
```

And then you can filter dynamically based on the query params. For instance to get a list of items where all query params match the given fields:

```
[item for item in q_namedtuple if all(getattr(item, k) == v for k, v in q_dict.iteritems())]
```

That is assuming the username in `q_dict` actually matched the field for username...it doesn't in your example but you can work around that. Similarly you could create a list of dicts, that'd make working with your list a bit easier:

```
q_list_of_dicts = [dict(zip(fields, x)) for x in q_list]
```

Which would give you a list of dicts like:

```
{'field1': '102.vmtest2',
 ...etc
 'queue': 'short',
 'username': 'John Dee'}
```

Then you can filter similarly:

```
[item for item in q_list_of_dicts if all(item.get(k) == v for k, v in q_dict.iteritems())]
```

Personally I think I prefer the dict approach. Whole things rolled up using for loops instead (and one generator expression):

```
results = []
for item in q_list:
    d = dict(zip(fields, item))
    # use some other logic to filter
    if all(d.get(k) == v for k, v in q_dict.iteritems()):
         results.append(d)
```

Comment: @zeekay: Thanks for the tips. I was looking for something more dynamic. The fact is, the query string could be the one in the example or like `user == sgmops && exechost == vmtest3.hep` or just `jobid == 103.vmtest2` - any of those fields. I want to handle this in dynamic manner. Cheers!!

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y, @zeekay: Looks like namedtuple() can't be used here as the `Type names and field names can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores`, according to the _ValueError_. I think it's complaining about all the `/` and `:` I have in the list. Can anyone confirm if I'm right or wrong? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers Just like it says, you can only have alphanumeric characters and underscores for your field names. I don't know what field names you are using, in my example i used `field1`, `username`, etc. If you want more flexibility in the field names you could use a dict instead of a namedtuple, perhaps just make a mapping of query param to tuple index.

Comment: ahhh... silly me! It's the fieldname, not the values - then I'm must be doing something wrong. Let me try again. Cheers!!

Comment: @zeekay: namedtuple() worked just fine and I got what I actually wanted. The problem is: part of my project's requirements force me to stick with python v2.4 (i.e. what comes default with RHEL-5) and namedtuple() was introduced in v2.6. Is there any way I can make this script v2.4 compatible? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers I haven't ever used 2.4, and I have no way to test it, but I updated my answer with another approach using dicts instead. Hopefully that will help

Comment: @zeekay: Using dict() was my actual idea but I couldn't make it out. Yes, your 'dict approach' kind of worked; `results` actually creating a list of dicts, rather a plain list only with the values. I'm trying to sort the keys first and then get rid of the keys to make a simple list with the values. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers just append item, instead of d

Comment: @zeekay: Thanks! I think I can take it from here. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would suggest that you store your data in `namedtuple`s or a custom class, instead of just raw tuples. This way you can access the attributes by name (e.g. by using `operator.attrgetter`). The other option is to use a `dict`.

Then, you can simply do the following (assuming your items are `dict`s):

```
[item for item in q_list if all((item[attr] == q_dict[attr]) 
                                 for q_dict in filters)]
```

This of course only works if your conditions always follow the pattern shown in your question (no `||`, no `!=` or stuff like that).

If you can only use tuples, then you can create a dictionary that maps the names of attributes to tuples-indices.

Now, when you print them, you can just create a list of attributes that should be printed, and use it like this:

```
for item in filtered_items:
    print "\t".join(item[attr] for attr in attributes_to_print) + "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

For the formatDate, it may be more complex, but for simple equality, you can use eval:

```
test_string = "username == 'John Dee' && queue == 'short'"

for a, b, username, formatDate, d, e, f, queue, g, h in q_list:
    if eval(test_string.replace('&&', 'and')):
        print '%s: %s' % (username, queue)
```

you can make 'or' statements by replacing '||' and this is fairly dynamic

don't forget to put the values in quotes (not `queue == short` but `queue == 'short'`)

the result on the given q_list is:

```
John Dee: short
John Dee: short
```

Comment: Ok, I feel myself obligates to give the usual *`eval`ing user-input is unsafe* comment. Do it at your own risk.

Comment: indeed, the right way to go should be to parse (probably with an AST) the input, and this should allow the date format handling

Answer (score 0):

once you have your user input parsed for the filter conditions, check each entry for each condition, saving a set of indices into q_list which match each individual condition, then do a set intersection to find the indices which match all of the conditions

in pseudo-ish code:

```
n = len(q_list)
accepted = set(range(n))
for condition in conditions:
  accepted = accepted.intersection({i for i in range(n) if condition_holds(q_list(i), condition)})

result = [q_list[i] for i in accepted]
```

Comment: If I try your suggestion I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for the line `accepted = accepted.intersection({i for i in range(n) if condition_holds(q_list(i), condition)})`, where the _for_ is. Any idea why I'm seeing this? Cheers!!

Comment: oh, your version of python probably doesn't support set comprehensions. try 'accepted = accepted.intersection(set((i for i in range(n) if condition_holds(q_list(i), condition)))' instead